# How can I import a file of filter into main.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way I can I have a file of filters and import them in?  I tried the following below but my linter keeps throwing errors saying the imported file is not used.

*main.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Filter from './filters.js'
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

*filters.js*

```
const Filter = Vue.filter('uppercase', function() {
    return "testing"
});

export Filter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to export your filters:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.filter('uppercase', function() {
   return "testing"
});
```

and just import it:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import './filters.js'
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

Comment: What is it's in a file with other exports?

Comment: What do you mean? To register a filter, it is enough to write `Vue.filter('filterName', handler)`. If it placed in a function just call it. If is exported, makes no sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Why you import filter but not using that?
you have two options:

1- inject filter to vue instant:

```js
import Filter from './filters.js';
Vue.prototype.filter = Filter;
```

then you can access to filter by `this.filter` in your components(like `this.$router`)

2- if you are using Eslint you can disable it for that line by writing an special comment above of it. [more info](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars)

Comment: `this.filter` is undefined when I do this.  The `Vue` instance has no value `filter` on it

Comment: that was a little mistake. use `Vue.prototype.filter =  Filter` instead.